# angular page not found 404 approutes const

Tags: angular

i have a problem when i try to load a page directly
this is the error message

> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
> use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

this is my app-routing.module.ts code :

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "home",
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  {
    path: "",
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "home",
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: "signup",
        component: SignUpComponent,
      },
      {
        path: "about",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./Pages/About/About.module").then((m) => m.AboutModule),
      },
      {
        path: "contact",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./Pages/Contact/Contact.module").then((m) => m.ContactModule),
      },
      {
        path: "artist",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./Pages/Artist/Artist.module").then((m) => m.ArtistModule),
      },
      {
        path: "chart",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./Pages/Chart/Chart.module").then((m) => m.ChartModule),
      },
      {
        path: "playlist",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./Pages/Playlist/Playlist.module").then((m) => m.PlaylistModule),
      },
      {
        path: "business",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./Pages/Business/Business.module").then((m) => m.BusinessModule),
      },
      {
        path: "blog",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./Pages/Blog/Blog.module").then((m) => m.BlogModule),
      },
      {
        path: "search",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./Pages/Search/Search.module").then((m) => m.SearchModule),
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { relativeLinkResolution: "legacy" }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

when i try to access direct to a page i got 404 error
what i can do?

Comment: it is not an angular error. provide information on how you serve your application

Comment: is it correct having 2 routes called `home` and one of them to be redirect to a child path? shouldn't the `path: home, componente: HomeComponent` be on the same level `MainComponent`?